# Proving in Dafny: A non-empty even sequence, is the concatenation of it's two halves

Tags: arrays, theorem-proving, dafny, formal-verification, induction

I would like to prove this "trivial" lemma in Dafny. A non-empty even sequence, is the concatenation of it's two halves:

```
lemma sequence_division(sequ:seq<int>)
    requires sequ != []
    requires even(|sequ|)
    ensures sequ[0..|sequ|] == sequ[0..(|sequ|/2)]+sequ[|sequ|/2+1..|sequ|]
    //{}
```

The problem is I am not used to prove inductive lemmas without the typical datatypes (using `match`...`case`...). Do I have to use `if` or something?

I tried:

```
lemma sequence_division(sequ:seq<int>)
    requires sequ != []
    requires even(|sequ|)
    ensures sequ[0..|sequ|] == sequ[0..(|sequ|/2)]+sequ[|sequ|/2+1..|sequ|]
    {
        if |sequ| == 2 { assert sequ[0..|sequ|] == sequ[0..(|sequ|/2)]+sequ[|sequ|/2+1..|sequ|]; }
        //if |sequ| == 2 { assert sequ[0..2] == sequ[0..1]+sequ[1..2];}
    }
```

And it marks it an `assertion violation` (so the if syntax seems to work), so probably I am expressing something bad. This is the last step of a full proof I am doing so this is last possibility is important.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the lemma does not hold, which makes it impossible to prove. In the right-hand side of the equality in the postcondition, you're skipping an element. Here is a correct version of the lemma's postcondition:

```
  ensures sequ[0..|sequ|] == sequ[0..|sequ|/2] + sequ[|sequ|/2..|sequ|]
```

The lower bounds default to `0` and the upper bounds default to `|sequ|`, so you can simplify the condition to

```
  ensures sequ == sequ[..|sequ|/2] + sequ[|sequ|/2..]
```

You can simplify the lemma further, because neither of the two preconditions is necessary for the postcondition to hold. Finally, if you care to, you can make the lemma more general by parameterizing over the sequence-element type:

```
lemma sequence_division<T>(sequ: seq<T>)
  ensures sequ == sequ[..|sequ|/2] + sequ[|sequ|/2..]
{
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thanks a lot. I got confused with the upper bound of the sequences, which are different from arrays. So, if the upper bound is (call it) n, then it means the sequence  reaches n-1.

Comment: It was also very curious because having this lemma unproven, when I used it, I was checked for obvious falsehoods such as assert 5==4.

Comment: The way to think of it is that `a[lo..hi]` skips the first `lo` elements and then gives you the next `hi - lo` elements. Dafny always uses half-open intervals like this. It also means that `a[lo..mid] + a[mid..hi] == a[lo..hi]`.